# HighStock Charts not Working over SSL ie https

Tags: highcharts

I have a site which is a secure site means, it is accessed using **https://** protocol.
This site has highchart on it.

The highchart was working perfectly when the protocol was **http://**.
But after installing secure certificate it failed to load in any browser.

I had imported the HighStock chart js as shown below.

Then I thought of changing the protocol for fetching the js from **http://** to **https://** as shown below

After this the chart started to render properly in internet explorer.

But the charts are still not loading in google Chrome,Firefox and Safari etc.

Can Anyone tell me the proper way to render/display HighStock chart over a site
that is accessed using **https://** protocol.

also the export and print functionality should also work.

This is a very urgent requirement, so any sort of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Soham Patel

Comment: If you want export via https, you have to setup your own exporting server.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing the protocol (http:) by doing this:

```
<script src="//www.myserver.com/js/HighStock/js/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem while using HighCharts where one of the required js library (highcharts-more.js) was referred using http when my app was running on https.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to look at, it's hard to tell, but one option is that you are loading some things with http and others with https. Make sure that everything in the page is using https e.g. All loaded scripts, etc.

Comment: No only the js files required by the charts use external js files mentioned in my query.Rest all are within my local project folder.