# Highcharts not loading when running on https

Tags: highcharts

We are facing problem on highcharts when running on https. It not getting rendered. But it is fine when running on HTTP.

Its not duplicate because here all the urls follows https

[Https Version](https://www.zawya.com/uae/en/company/Emaar_Properties_PJSC-5519/)

[Http version](http://www.zawya.com/uae/en/company/Emaar_Properties_PJSC-5519/)

Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HighStock Charts not Working over SSL ie https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540372/highstock-charts-not-working-over-ssl-ie-https)

Comment: Have you investigated this error that occurs onyour https site? `TypeError: a.renderTo is undefined` You also have a couple of `Blocked loading mixed active content` errors which could be causing a problem.

Comment: @jlbriggs nope, one blocked url is ad related and highcharts not getting rendered even no mixed content

Comment: What about the other error? Have you verified that `chart:{renderTo:a[0]}` is populating the expected value?

Comment: Yes values are getting populated and I have verified today it is working on local environment when running over https, Only I have issue on live. But no clue what goes wrong